# Browser freezes while uploading large image

Tags: php, upload

I am using this uploader: http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/
and when I upload a picture of camera quality the browser freezes for couple minutes. When I upload a normal quality picture, for example the default Windows sample pictures, it does not freeze.

What's the problem?
Are there any alternative uploaders that you could suggest?

Comment: You're uploading directly from the camera? Then the problem is likely there, maybe the card/USB connection is slow?

Comment: If you're uploading directly from a peripheral, then the speed is going to be greatly hit by the IO time.

Comment: No no, directly from my pc. Its becomes becuase the size of the picture

Comment: No idea what the problem is ?